# how to make getting data faster from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in programming and in iOS development. I am trying to make an app using Firestore database from Firebase. I don't know if it is normal or not, but when I am trying to get a data from firestore database, it seems too long for me. I don't know if I make a mistake or not

here is my code to get all city data from firestore

reference :

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

enum FirestoreCollectionReference {
    case users
    case events
    case cities

    private var path : String {
        switch self {
        case .users : return "users"
        case .events : return "events"
        case .cities : return "cities"
        }
    }

    func reference () -> CollectionReference {
        return Firestore.firestore().collection(path)
    }
}
```

I use `getAllCitiesDataFromFirestore` method in `CityKM` class to get the city data that stored in firestore

```
class CityKM {
    var name : String
    var coordinate : GeoPoint

    init (name: String , coordinate: GeoPoint ) {
        self.name = name
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }

    init (dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        // this init will be used if we get data from firebase observation to construct an event object

        name = dictionary["name"] as! String
        coordinate = dictionary["coordinate"] as! GeoPoint
    }

    static func getAllCitiesDataFromFirestore (completion: @escaping ( [CityKM]? )->Void) {
        // to retrieve all cities data from Firebase database by one read only, not using realtime fetching listener

        let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() // to track time consumption of this method

        FirestoreCollectionReference.cities.reference().getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to retrieve all cities data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Sucessfully get all cities data from firestore")

                guard let documentsSnapshot = snapshot, !documentsSnapshot.isEmpty else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }

                let citiesDocuments = documentsSnapshot.documents
                var cityArray = [CityKM]()

                for document in citiesDocuments {
                    guard let cityName = document.data()["name"] as? String,
                          let cityCoordinate = document.data()["coordinate"] as? GeoPoint else {return}

                    let theCity = CityKM(name: cityName, coordinate: cityCoordinate)
                    cityArray.append(theCity)
                }

                completion(cityArray)

                let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime // to track time consumption of this method
                print("Time needed to get all cities data from Firestore : \(timeElapsed) s.") // to track time consumption of this method

            }
        }
    }


}



extension CityKM {

    // MARK: - User Helper Methods
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]{
        return [
            "name" : name,
            "coordinate" : coordinate
        ]
    }


}
```

from my debugging area, it is printed

> "Time needed to get all cities data from Firestore : 1.8787678903 s."

is it possible to make it faster? Is 1.8s normal? am i make a mistake in my code that make the request data takes too long time ? I hope that I can make request time is below one second

I don't think the internet speed is the problem, since I can open video on youtube without buffering

Comment: I see about the same response time.  It's not excessive.  If you need it instantly, you could think about downloading it async in the background before you need it.  Also, if you don't need all the data in one hit, you could use `.limit(to: x)` and fetch further data as and when you need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That performance sounds a bit worse than what I see, but nothing excessive. Loading data from the cloud simply takes time. A quick approach to hide that latency is by making use of Firebase's built-in caching.

When you call `getDocuments`, the Firebase client needs to check on the server what the document's value is *before* it can call your code, which then shows the value to the user. As said: there is no way to speed up this reading in your code, so it'll always take at least 1.8s before the user sees a document.

If instead you [listen for realtime updates from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) with `addSnapshotListener`, the Firebase client may be able to immediately call your code with values from its local cache, and then later re-invoke your code in case there has been an update to the data on the server.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank for your answer :) , I am new in programming and of course I am also new in Firebase. it seems there is two way to getting data from Firebase, by realtime update addSnapshotListener or by using getDocuments. but I can't distinguish when I have to use one than the other? I mean real time update seems amazing, so why I have to use getDocuments? do you have article to distinguish these two? Thanks in advance Frank :)

Comment: The older Realtime Database heavily promoted the realtime updates. In fact, its equivelent to `getDocuments()` is really a quick listen-wait-stop-listening sequence. Many developers found that harder to use than the more common `get` approach. In Firestore both `get` and `listen` are first-class citizens. You can use whichever one you want. But since `get()` only gives you a result once, it will usually have to first check with the server to ensure you're not seeing stale data from the cache.

Comment: I have a collection with around 5000 documents and using snapshotListener is returning me results faster then getdocuments. My problem is if multiple documents get updated at the same time my tableview was freezing for a while which made UX little bit worse.